# libzip external library inclusion in xcode project

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, libzip

Currently I am including an external library in my `xcode` project. I have included the libraries manually in my project, so I am able to get all the library function. There is no any compile time errors, but when I am running I am getting `runtime error` somewhat like mentioned bellow

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_zip_error_to_str", referenced from:
>         Greeting::Greeting() in Myzipclass.o
>     "_zip_open", referenced from:
>         Greeting::Greeting() in Myzipclass.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've included `libzip` libraries in to my project.

More details: I haven't included any framework. Is it necessary to include framework? I am totally new in `xcode`. If it is necessary to include framework then can anyone tell me procedures to include? I mean, should it be inside the project?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide more details about how you add libzip to you xcode project.

Comment: i added lib directory from the archive given at this link  http://www.nih.at/libzip/index.html    .. manually added lib directory and included it.. i have added screen shots of them please check.

Answer (score 0):

Just concluded from the error info, See if static library libz.1.X.X.dylib have been added to `xcode`. Otherwise,

> targets--->build phases----->link binary with libraries-----> add libz

Comment: libz.1.1.3.tdb is alredy added lulyon still it is showing the same linker error

Comment: @AbhinandanDharmadikari Please check if the library placed in the wrong directory, cause the `Undefined symbols ` makes it very clear that the intended lib is not linked to your executable.